# trying to create a css column sub menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

So I'm trying to create a css menu, where the children are in a column format. But I cannot seem to get the child li's to float, displaying their ul's underneath them. I can't seem to get the parent ul to be the width of the child, it seems to want to remain the width of the parent (I hope this is making sense).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-112 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=112">Accommodation</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-161 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=161">Property Type</a>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-149"><a href="/?Itemid=149">Apartments</a></li>
            <li class="item-150"><a href="/?Itemid=150">Suites</a></li>
            <li class="item-151"><a href="/?Itemid=151">Penthouses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-179 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=179">Information</a>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-152"><a href="/?Itemid=152">Inclusions</a></li>
            <li class="item-162"><a href="/?Itemid=162">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-113"><a href="/?Itemid=167">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.header ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
.header ul li{position:relative;float:left;display:inline;margin:0;padding:0}
.header ul li > a{padding:25px 15px;font-size:20px;line-height:20px;color:#666;font-weight:800;text-transform:uppercase;display:block}
.header ul li.item-101 > a{padding-left:0}
.header ul li.active > a,
.header ul li > a:hover{color:#1a2440}

.header ul li > ul{position:absolute;left:-9999em;width:auto;min-width:100%;max-width:500px;background:rgb(255,255,255);background:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);border:solid 1px #eaeaea}
.header ul li > ul li{float:left;display:inline-block;background:#f0f}
.header ul li > ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
.header ul li > ul li > a{padding:13px 15px;margin:0;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;color:#006699;font-weight:800;text-transform:uppercase;background:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap}
.header ul li > ul li.active > a,
.header ul li > ul li > a:hover{color:#009fe3}

.header ul li > ul li > ul{position:relative;float:none;display:block;top:0;left:0;background:none;border:none}
.header ul li > ul li > ul li{float:none;display:block;top:0;left:0;border-top:solid 1px #d7d7d7;background:#f9f}

.header ul li.parent:hover > a{color:#1a2440}
.header ul li.parent:hover > ul{left:0}
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SoulieBaby/UDPDg/) of what I've currently got, but I want the children of the Accommodation drop down to behave like columns. Which it's currently *not* doing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a sceenshot of how you want and what are you getting currently?

Comment: http://fallscreek.website.2013.360southclients.com/screenshot.jpg

Comment: I essentially want each child (pink) li to sit next to each other, not underneath each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/UDPDg/4/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item-112 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=112">Accommodation</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-161 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=161">Property Type</a>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-149"><a href="/?Itemid=149">Apartments</a></li>
            <li class="item-150"><a href="/?Itemid=150">Suites</a></li>
            <li class="item-151"><a href="/?Itemid=151">Penthouses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-179 deeper parent"><a href="/?Itemid=179">Information</a>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class="item-152"><a href="/?Itemid=152">Inclusions</a></li>
            <li class="item-162"><a href="/?Itemid=162">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-113"><a href="/?Itemid=167">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.header ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
.header ul li{position:relative;float:left;display:inline;margin:0;padding:0}
.header ul li > a{padding:25px 15px;font-size:20px;line-height:20px;color:#666;font-weight:800;text-transform:uppercase;display:block}
.header ul li.item-101 > a{padding-left:0}
.header ul li.active > a,
.header ul li > a:hover{color:#1a2440}

.header ul li > ul{position:absolute;left:-9999em;width:auto;min-width:100%;max-width:500px;background:rgb(255,255,255);background:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);border:solid 1px #eaeaea}
.header ul li > ul li{float:left;display:inline-block;background:#f0f}
.header ul li > ul li:last-child{border-bottom:none}
.header ul li > ul li > a{padding:13px 15px;margin:0;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;color:#006699;font-weight:800;text-transform:uppercase;background:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap}
.header ul li > ul li.active > a,
.header ul li > ul li > a:hover{color:#009fe3}

.header ul li > ul li > ul{position:relative;float:none;display:block;top:0;left:0;background:none;border:none}
.header ul li > ul li > ul li{float:none;display:block;top:0;left:0;border-top:solid 1px #d7d7d7;background:#f9f}

.header ul li.parent:hover > a{color:#1a2440}
.header ul li.parent:hover > ul{left:0}


.header ul li > ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    left: -9999em;
    max-width: 1010px;
    min-width: 356px;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}


.header ul li > ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF00FF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 178px;
}

.header ul li > ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF00FF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 178px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

To work with dynamic width, here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/UDPDg/14/)**

Comment: Thanks for that :) I should've said that I wanted the width to be dynamic, not fixed (min-width:356px) and (width:178px). So if there's say three children, it will display 3 columns. Is that even possible with CSS, or do I need to use jquery to set the widths?

Comment: Yes. It can be done with CSS. Here yo go. http://jsfiddle.net/UDPDg/14/ I have edited the same above. - @SoulieBaby

Comment: I have made further edits. Check the latest for a full fledged solution. - @SoulieBaby

Answer (score 0):

here I make a menu with a submenu with all columns that you want ;)

HTML

```
<ul id="wrap">
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    <div class="subwrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    <div class="subwrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#wrap > li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#wrap li:hover .subwrap {
    display: block;
}
#wrap li .subwrap {
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
}
#wrap li .subwrap ul {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap li .subwrap ul:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#wrap li .subwrap ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hendrymc/8D5T4/